# Missing functionality of Imagej variant Fiji

Tags: imagej

I am trying to use a variant of ImageJ, Fiji for analysis of some microscopy images. When I try to "Open Next" to get to the net image, nothing happens.

In the standard version of ImageJ this feature works, and raises an error if it fails.

It seems like some underlying code is missing. I have been unable to find posts that seem to have the same issue. Could it be that I am missing some module for this to work? Could it be somethiing to do with Java?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: With my up-to-date Fiji installation on Mac OSX, *Open Next* works as expected. It might be a file system-specific bug though. Please report the bug via *Help > Report a bug*, so the relevant information about your system is transmitted to the developers.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a file type-specific issue with *File > Open Next*: when handling *.czi* files (and other files usually opened using Bio-Formats), the `ij.io.Opener#getFileType(path)` method returns the wrong type and leads to failure of the search for the next file. See [this thread](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Open-Next-not-working-tp5008920.html) on the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html).